# Basic: ViewController Hierachy

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

In the first view controller A I call the "presentModalViewController" and then the B view controller is added to the screen now.

The question is, is it true that the "A" view controller is still in the memory? Which means, will the viewDidLoad method be called after I had pop the "B" view controller out of the screen?

And what about calling the pushModalViewController method? Will the first view controller stay in the memory?

Comment: Do you mean `UIViewController` when talking about A and B? You should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot push or present a view, it must be a `UIViewController`.
Secondly answer to your question it is true, when pushing or presenting "B" ViewController, "A" still remains in memory. 
`viewDidLoad` of "A" does not called when "B" ViewController is Popped off the stack.
If you want a function in A ViewController, that should always called then you can use

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

These will be called even after "B" ViewController is Popped off.

Comment: and what's the different btw the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods? When will them be called respectively?

Comment: viewWillAppear: Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a view hierarchy. Means this method is called just before ViewController is Appeared.
See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:

viewDidAppear: Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy. Means this method is called just after the view is appeared